# Oracle writes whole file during database creation is it ok?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, tablespaces

Consider empty (!) database creation:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE reload DATAFILE 'D:\myDb.dbf'  SIZE 3000M  ONLINE;
```

This is leads to writring 3000 megabytes to the disk for empty database. Is it normal for oracle? I am new to oracle database, did I miss something important in `CREATE TABLESPACE` which leads to such behavior?

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to create this tablespace(logical entity of Oracle database to hold user objects) then you already have  created the database.

Yes, this is expected. The statement defines a datafile of 300MB size in underlying storage.

You can also auto increment size. For example, initially you have defined its size  as 300M. When you create new objects and perform DML, they will use this space. Once this 300M is consumed by objects you need to either add new datafile or increase its size or let the Oracle increment its size as needed.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE tbs_02 
   DATAFILE '/diskb/tbs_f5.dbf' SIZE 500K REUSE
   AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 500K MAXSIZE 100M;
```

It creates a tablespace called `tbs_02`with a datafile of `500K` initial size. Once the `500K` is occupied by objects it will be incremented by `500K` at once and grows upto `100MB`.

If you are new to Oracle database I strongly suggest you to follow [Oracle Concepts Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/toc.htm)

**Reference:**

[CREATE TABLESPACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7003.htm#i2202468)

[storage_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses009.htm#SQLRF30013)

Comment: "You may assign few megabytes at the beginning and define auto increment as needed" - but created db is empty. I understand if it allocates empty file with 3000M, but it *writes* to this file.

Comment: You have defined 300M which which creates data file of 300MB on the underlying file system. What I mean is you could also allocate 100M at first and define auto increment as `create tablespace tbs1 datafile 'path/name.dbf` size 100M autoextend on next 1M maxsize 2G`

Comment: Could you please provide a full statement for creating table space with incrementing file? Because when I try `CREATE TABLESPACE reload
  DATAFILE 'D:\myFile.dbf'
  SIZE 1M
  DEFAULT STORAGE (INITIAL 100M MAXSIZE 3G)  ONLINE;` It fails later, because `myFile.dbf` **restricted** to 1M and not increases to 3G.

Comment: The problem is you defined initial extent size in storage clause. It means, when you create a object on the tablespace Oracle will assign 100M as a initial extent of the segment(objects such as table). Refer to my lasted update for details about creating tablespace and storage clause.

Comment: @Cherry "…it *writes* to this file…" sure, the file (and each block within it) needs to be initialized: https://community.oracle.com/thread/722274?start=15&tstart=0